# Using Matlab to plot a cylinder bounded by a plane

Tags: matlab

I'm able to draw a cylinder of radius 1 and the plane z=x+2 using the Symbolic Math Toolbox in Matlab.

```
%% 
clc
close all

syms x y z t
r=1
fsurf(r*cos(t),r*sin(t),z,[0,2*pi,0,7])
hold on
fsurf(@(x,y) x+5,[-2,2,-2,2])
```

However, what I want to do is draw the cylinder bounded below by the xy-plane and above by the plane z=x+2. Can anyone give me a suggestion how to do this? I'd appreciate an answer using the Symbolic Toolbox, and if possible, another answer using numerical Matlab.

Thanks.

David

**Update:** I've found a numeric solution.

```
clc
close all

t=meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,100));
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=meshgrid(linspace(0,5,100))';
z(z>x+2)=NaN;
surf(x,y,z)
colormap jet
hold on

[x,y]=meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,500),linspace(-1,1,500));
z=x+2;
z(x.^2+y.^2>1)=NaN;
surf(x,y,z,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none')

hold off
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

However, this will be difficult for students, so here are two things I'd like to know.

1. Is there a nice parametric way to do this using Matlab?
2. Is there a nice parametric way to do this using Symbolic Math Toolbox?

**Second Update:** I've discovered a way to use the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

```
clc
close all

syms r t u
fsurf(cos(t),sin(t),u*(cos(t)+2),[0,2*pi,0,1])
hold on

fsurf(r*cos(t),r*sin(t),r*cos(t)+2,[0,1,0,2*pi],'FaceColor','r')

rotate3d on
```

This code produces this image:

[image]