# Change in plot result using syms variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, plot

I was trying an example about using fsurf using a code from this tread ( [Using Matlab to plot a cylinder bounded by a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333829/using-matlab-to-plot-a-cylinder-bounded-by-a-plane) ).

The problem comes when I change the name of a declared syms variable the output of the graph changes completely, which I don´t really understand.
Here is the output using the original code:

```
symObj = syms;
cellfun(@clear,symObj)
clear all 
close all
syms r t u
fsurf(cos(r),sin(r),u*(cos(r)+2),[0,2*pi,0,1])
hold on
fsurf(r*cos(t),r*sin(t),r*cos(t)+2,[0,1,0,2*pi],'FaceColor','r')
rotate3d on
```

fsurf result:
[image: fsurf result]

and here is the same example in which I only changed the name of the variable 't' to 'phi' in the declaration variable and the three places it was used in:

```
symObj = syms;
cellfun(@clear,symObj)
clear all 
close all
syms r phi u
fsurf(cos(r),sin(r),u*(cos(r)+2),[0,2*pi,0,1])
hold on
fsurf(r*cos(phi),r*sin(phi),r*cos(phi)+2,[0,1,0,2*pi],'FaceColor','r')
rotate3d on
```

fsurf result with alternative variable name:
[image: fsurf result with alternative variable name]

Comment: What are the two statements before `clear all` meant to do? By the way, `clear all` removes loaded functions from memory, which is rarely useful and slows down your code. Better to use `clear` to only clear all variables from memory.

Comment: Thank you for the tip os using `clear` instead of `clear all`. I added the first four lines just in case the previous script was affecting the new one in some way, as I don´t understand very much how syms variables and fsurf works internally.

Comment: Oh, I see what it’s doing now. `clear` will clear all variables, so there is no need to manually clear those specific variables first. But good that you try to reset everything to avoid any possible conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t have the symbolic toolbox installed at the moment to test this out, but I think this is the problem: `fsurf` is given two intervals to plot in as a single vector: `[0,1,0,2*pi]`. One variable will run from 0 to 1, another from 0 to 2 pi. But which variable will be given each interval?

Since there is no explicit ordering of variables in the function call, all `fsurf` can do is sort them alphabetically. Usually people use x and y, or u and v, which are sorted alphabetically. Note that the order in which you originally declared the variables is not recorded anywhere in MATLAB, this information can only be recovered by examining the source code that was run to declare those variables. `fsurf` certainly doesn’t know the order in which you think of these variables.

The first code uses variables r and t, the second one uses phi and r. Switching the order of the two intervals in the interval array should fix your issue if my guess is right.

Comment: You were completely right, changing the order of the intervals in fsurf fixed my problem. I´ll be more aware of the order from now on!! Thank you very much Cris

Comment: This was driving me crazy!
Is there any way to specify the order?

Comment: @MySurmise you probably need to declare the three functions passed into `fsurf` explicitly, like so: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-functions.html